# Nagata Smirnov Metrization Theorem

Tags: general-topology, reference-request

I am looking for a proof for Nagata-Smirnov Metrization Theorem, but I couldn't find one that is readable. I found the paper by Nagata written in 1954 but it is unreadable and uses old notation. Anyone knows where to find the proof?

Comment: It is in Munkres.

Comment: I think many (if not most) topology texts would have a proof: Munkres, Engelking, Dugundji, Kelley, Willard (though it isn't named in the last two texts).

Comment: can you give me the link of original paper??